Python unittest how to mock a passed in class
Trying to unittest a method that receives a class as an argument but unsure how to mock it right
I am trying to unittest this method `
def get_local_path(p4_path, p4):
    if p4_path.endswith('...'):
        p4_path = p4_path.replace('/...', '')
    path = p4.run("where", p4_path)[0]
    for key, value in list(path.items()):
            if key == 'path':
                path = value.replace('\\', '/')
                return path

The method receives p4 as an argument from a different script, and p4 is the p4python class (its already instantiated), so i can run p4 commands.  I am trying to learn how to unittest and really unsure how to go about mocking this.  I tried to patch it but that didn't work, and then i tried to create a Mock object and pass it in but I have no idea how to deal with when it calls the .run.
def test_get_local_path(self):
    mock_p4 = mock.Mock()
    # not sure what to do here, or how to get it to assign return value to p4.run
    get_local_path('//mypath/test', mock_p4)


Simply assign the desired return value to p4.run.return_value:
def test_get_local_path(self):
    mock_p4 = mock.Mock()
    p4.run.return_value = "..."
    get_local_path('//mypath/test', mock_p4)


oh this also works in addition to the way i found using patch.  Not sure which way is best.  Also I assume you mean to type in mock_p4.run.return_value = "...".
thanks!

patch is basically a way to assign to a variable you can't (or don't want to) otherwise assign to. Function parameters are special in that you can control assignment to them, by passing arguments to the function call. (For example, if get_local_path were using a global p4 instead of taking some object as an argument, you would need patch to temporarily replace the value of the global variable. )

oh i found a way to use patch to get a desired result, not sure if this a right way to do this or not.  Adding in the create=True got through some errors.
@mock.patch('main.p4', create=True)
def test_get_local_path(self, mock_p4):
    mock_p4.run.return_value = ['test']
    self.assertEqual(get_local_path(path, mock_p4), 'test')


I made a short example with a class P4, and a somewhat shorter function get_local_path. Hope this helps:
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class P4:
    def run(self):
        return "foo"


def get_local_path(path, p4):
    return p4.run(path)

def test_get_local_path():
    mock_p4 = MagicMock(spec=P4)
    mock_p4.run.return_value = "run_p4"
    get_local_path('//mypath/test', mock_p4)
    mock_p4.run.assert_called_once_with('//mypath/test')

This test passes

If you are defining a new P4 class, there's no need for a Mock object; you can simply pass an instance of P4 as the argument. You can also use p4 itself as the spec (or spec_set) argument for a Mock instead of defining a new stub class.

I know that. I don't know what P4 was from the original question. I simply added this class  to make a full working example.

So the 'P4' class in my example was meant to mimic the original 'P4'the question referred to. Not as a stub. I thought it would make my answer better understandable. But I guess it was confusing.
